# Why is n given the initial value of 1 in this loop?

Tags: c

From Kochan's "Programming in C":

**Input:**

```
printf ("TABLE OF TRIANGULAR NUMBERS\n\n"); 
printf (" n Sum from 1 to n\n");
printf ("--- ---------------\n");
triangularNumber = 0;
for(n=1; n<=10; ++n){ 
    triangularNumber += n;
￼    printf (" %i", n);
}
```

**Output (only partly pasted):**

TABLE OF TRIANGULAR NUMBERS

n = 1

Sum from 1 to n = 1

n = 2

Sum from 1 to n = 2

**Question**:

I understand the purpose of this, but here's what I can't get my head around: If within the loop we assign an initial value of "1" to "n", then we check if n<=10, and if that's true (which it should be with the initial value), we then add "1" to n. Shouldn't (and I know it shouldn't, just don't understand why) the initial value displayed in our table be n=2 ?

Thanks in advance for your patience and effort!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`++n` happens after the body of the loop is run, not before.

```
for(n=1; n<=10; ++n){ 
   triangularNumber += n;
￼   printf (" %i", n);
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
n=1; // happen before the loop
while(n<=10){ // becomes the conditional test
   triangularNumber += n;
￼   printf (" %i", n);
   ++n; // happens at the end of the list
}
```

Comment: I haven't reached the "while" statement yet but your first sentence made it clear enough for me. Thank you, sir.